# How to pass model to WebApi controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I am in need to write WebApi controllers. The task is to migrate from exisitng normal mvc controller to WebApi controllers.

In this projects, almost all the beauty of the programming is used like:-

- Design Patterns - Repository + UOW, Factory + nUnit
- Dependency Injection
- SOLID

This is my model in the `MyApp.Domain` layer

```
public class Customer
{
   //please note that we are using Repository pattern & so no Data Annotations like Required, Key are not used here. 
   public int CustomerID { get; set;}

   public string CustomerName { get; set;}

   public string EmailAddress { get; set;}
   // & so on
}
```

In the `MyApp.UI` layer, exists ViewModel for validation & then passing the model to Service layer that. So this is how my MVC controllers looks like

```
  public class CustomerVM
  {
     [Required]
     public int CustomerID { get; set;}  // & so on the other properties.

  }


  public ActionResult Registration(Customer VM)
  {
         if(Modelstate.IsValid)
         {
            //call service layer 
         }
         else
         {

         }
  }
```

Now my immediate task is to migrate this controller to WebApi controller.
Henceforth, I created a separate project as `MyApp.WebApi`

Now my doubt is how should I pass the model to this WebApi controller.

I am thinking to detach the ViewModel from UI layer to separate
project as `MyApp.ViewModels` and put all the viewmodels in this layer
& reference the dll in UI layer & WebApi layer.

```
 public string POST([FromBody]CustomerVM customer)
 {
    if(Modelstate.IsValid)
    {
        //call the other service layer which will take care of DB handling
       return "Success";
    }
    else
    {
       return "Error";
    }   
 }
```

Is this the right way to do & any other right way to do this??

Comment: it should be fine if you do that .

Comment: @YashveerSingh, are you sure on this??

Comment: So if this i what I understood . You want to convert an existing MVC project to WebApi . So you can use your existing view model as you were using in VC project  web api can do model bindings as mvc does.

Comment: @YashveerSingh
Yes.You got my requirment right.

Comment: OK so reusing same VM should not be an issue . But I have one question are you planning to have a new client side UI . I mean are you going to create a nee client side application which will consume webapi ?

Comment: @YashveerSingh, No I don't think so for now. But in case if the client plans, it shouldn't be a blocking factor.

Comment: ok and how you are going to consume this webapi in your existing project which has all cshtml with razor model bindings?

Comment: @YashveerSingh,This WebApi will be deployed on a separate server & UI will call this Api via ajax or form submit anything. Do I make sense to you??

Comment: yup that is what I want to ask . I think you already  have everything sorted out correctly to me it looks good . Let see some more experienced comment on this

Comment: @YashveerSingh. Thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 1):

In a RESTful API, what you call *view models* are *DTOs* or in the Web API slang, they're *models*.

You know that both ASP.NET MVC and WebAPI have similar architecture, and in ASP.NET MVC Core they've been merged into a single programming model. That is, what was valid in ASP.NET MVC is also valid in WebAPI.

Check that you don't need `[FromBody]` attribute. *Models* are bound from the body automatically.

Comment: Should I take your post as "my approach is correct"?

Comment: @Kgn-web Indeed. It seems correct, and other details might be more suitable for SE.CodeReview. I mean, if you want to validate that your actual code is fine not only in terms of software layering...

Answer (score 1):

you can also use IHttpActionResult instead of string and throw an actual error.

```
public IHttpActionResult  POST([FromBody] CustomerVM customer)
 {
   if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
     return Ok("success");

 }
```

Comment: just a note I noticed you said something about api on separate server and you are going to call it via AJAX you may need to look into enabling cors. https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Yes, I will be enabling CORS & then add domains.   & Thanks for your inputs :)